# Python SQLite3 OperationalError: table shop has 2 columns but 3 values were supplied

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord.py

I was creating a discord bot, and when I used a command(!add-item @Role 15), it crashed with: "OperationalError: table shop has 2 columns but 3 values were supplied"! Here code is:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import sqlite3

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (
        role_id INT,
        id INT,
        cost BIGINT
    )""")

@client.command(aliases = ['add-item'])
async def __add_item(ctx, role: discord.Role = None, cost: int = None):
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.author}**, please, choose a role!')
    else:
        if cost is None:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, please, indicate the cost of the role!")
        elif cost < 0:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, the cost of the role must be higher than 0!")
        else:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO shop VALUES ({}, {}, {})".format(role.id, ctx.guild.id, cost))
            connection.commit()

            await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')

client.run('MY TOKEN')
```

**Please help!**

Comment: You should use the DB-API’s parameter substitution instead of Python format .Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s execute() method. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: You may have created your table with 2 columns once. Try to remove the `server.db` file and re-launch your application.

Comment: Laurent LAPORTE, working, thanks so much!